# Wordpress error: 'The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads'

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I've tried updating permissions to every possible combination for both the wp-content folder and also the uploads folder within it and it hasn't remedied the issue.

I also saw in a few threads of similar issues that adding

```
define('FTP_PUBKEY','/home/wp-user/wp_rsa.pub');
define('FTP_PRIKEY','/home/wp-user/wp_rsa');
define('FTP_USER','wp-user');
define('FTP_PASS','');
define('FTP_HOST','127.0.0.1:22');
```

to the wp-config file could help, so I tried that and now my site is getting an error 500 and not loading at all despite me having since removed the above code.

I know this question has been asked before but I've tried most of the solutions and have only managed to make the problem worse... any suggestions how to get the site working again after my blunder?

Comment: Turn on PHP and WordPress error reporting. If all you did was add that and then remove it, there's a good chance there's a minor typo in the file still, like a missing semi-colon or an extra parenthesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting incase this happens to anyone else. The hosting account for the site was at its data limit so the error for uploading was because there was no space to upload the files to and not the expected read/wright permissions.

When I updated the code on the page, instead of saving it saved the page as a blank template because again - no room left to save the file to.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I had the same issue and couldn't fix it.

Permissions were correct, there was enough storage.

What fixed it for me was deleting the month folder (08 in my case) and when reuploading image, website recreated the folder and it worked fine :)